# Push value to DucksBoard in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I going to implement the `DucksBoard API`. I made my custom counter on Ducksboard now I want to `PUSH` value. I read the tutorial I just found this line on `DUCKSBOARD` to push data

```
curl -v -u YOUR_API_KEY:unused -d '{"value": 10}' https://push.ducksboard.com/values/235
```

SO i try something like this in my Coldfusion code

```
<cfset var1 = '{"value":5}'>  

    <cfhttp url="https://push.ducksboard.com/values/xxxx" method="post" result="httpResp" timeout="60">
        <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/json" />
        <cfhttpparam type="body" value="#serializeJSON(var1)#">
    </cfhttp>
```

There is less information in the site of Duckboard.Can someone has implemented this.If yes then kindly tell me how to push value and where to use my API key?

Comment: And what happened when you tried that code?  Please share any errors or messages that were returned or that you have found in the log files.

Comment: It looks like he just wasn't sure how to use the API key in `cfhttp` as opposed to any real issue with the code.

Comment: @Jarede you are right I am confused where to use that API key in `<cfhttp>`. this is link for actual site http://dev.ducksboard.com/apidoc/push-api/#push-api

Comment: @Azam Alvi so if you look at my answer, looking through the documents, you just need to put the API key in the `username` part of the `cfhttp` and can ignore `password`

Comment: I have done this before but I was getting error of `401 Unauthorized`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I study the API and found the solution You can use this code and change with yours this will work.And don't use `serializeJSON` in body tag.

```
<cfset var1 = '{"value":5}'>  

    <cfhttp url="https://push.ducksboard.com/v/xxxx" method="post" username="API-key" password="x"  result="httpResp" >
        <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/json" />
        <cfhttpparam type="body" value='#var1#'>
    </cfhttp>
```

Comment: *And don't use serializeJSON in body tag.* Good spot. The original string is already in JSON format. However, if you are going to be sending anything more complex than `{"value":5}`, it is better not to DIY. Just use CF structures and arrays, and let serializeJSON construct the JSON for you.

Answer (score 3):

I've not used Duckboard but it looks like what you have is correct.  The `CFHTTP` tag takes 2 more parameters, `username` and `password` which you can fill in with your username and your API password like so:

```
<cfset var1 = '{"value":5}'>  

<cfhttp url="https://push.ducksboard.com/values/xxxx" method="post"
    result="httpResp" timeout="60" username="myusername" password="mypassword"
    >
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/json" />
    <cfhttpparam type="body" value="#serializeJSON(var1)#">
</cfhttp>
```